# Web Deployment using IIS , folder missing

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, directory, web-deployment

I have deployed my website to IIS 7. The deployed web will be on www inetpub folder.
My project folder is on another destination.

I have a habit of testing my web using the debugging mode on Visual Studio instead of going to the localhost web on IIS to test. So in my code, I create a folder in the project folder, but the folder that is being created by the code is not reflected in the www inetpub folder. Is this because I test it using debugging mode instead of going on the hosted web?

How can I show the folder being created by the code in the www inetpub folder? 
Is the only way to copy paste the folder and test it using the hosted website from then onwards? Advice needed.

Comment: How you creating folder? please send code for more details

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you need to create the folder and insert a dummy file on it, that happens to me by the time you build your solution, the VS simply ignores the directories that are "not relevant" to the solution.

create in the your folder are a file as follows:
/myFolder/dummy.txt

where dummy.txt is a blank txt file and myfolder is the folder you want to keep after the build of your solution.